# disable global app menu in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, 19.04, gnome-shell, appmenu

In Ubuntu 18.x, the global app menu could be disabled with this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '@a{sv} {"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu":<0>}'
```

Or, using gnome-tweaks, I would turn it off by clicking on *Top Bar* -> *Application Menu*.

However, neither of these seems to work anymore in Ubuntu 19.04.  What is the new correct way to disable the global app menu?

---

**Edit:**
Note that I cannot use the hamburger menu as not every application has one of those.  For example, on my desktop I have Terminator and KDevelop running, neither of which have a hamburger menu.  The global menu at the top of the screen (not attached to the window) has options specific to those applications:
[image: screenshot of global menu]

How would I disable this global menu and bring whatever menu options are provided down to the application's window instead?

Comment: Indeed, well noticed. Although the option is still there in Gnome Tweaks, it indeed does not anymore remove the application menu. Note, however, that no program exposes its own options there anymore: it now all moved within the hamburger menu of the application window itself. The application menu now will contain only a "Quit" option and eventually some launcher actions which you also have right-clicking the launcher.

Comment: AFAIK Gnome 3.32 was going to remove the application menu, it seems they only removed from the window decoration.
The option you mention just moved the menu from the topbar to the window decoration so that option is now deprecated, I find quite annoying that menu in the topbar panel too

Comment: @vanadium The default options now are "Show Details", "Quit" and a list with the titles of every window of the application. Plus, many apps expose options in it; Firefox, Chrome and their derivatives have actions for new tabs and windows, for instance. Also, GNOME Terminal, which has a hamburger menu, shows options in the top bar.

Comment: @JPdelaTorre Indeed they now included launcher actions in the menu, so it still does more than showing the current application. However, I do not anymore see an option to remove it from the top bar.

Comment: The options you see now are not provided by the application themselves anymore (i.e. in case of Gnome applications), but by the launcher. Thus, you will never be able to bring these into the application.

Comment: @vanadium Oh, I see. You are right. However, the title bar on windows is provided by GNOME. That means these options could live within the title bar.

Comment: Mora information about removing [those menus](https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2018/10/09/farewell-application-menus/)

Answer (score 2):

I started using the [Hide App Icon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/810/hide-app-icon/) extension. It works perfectly and you can choose to hide the app icon, the window title, and the dropdown arrow independently.